# MySQL: Get POSITION of Non-ASCII character

Tags: mysql, regex, string

I have an example string like,

> "Kim_!@$Maria"

The `'_'` could be anything that is not a **letter** or a **number.** So I want to find the position of the first **non-Numeric/Alphabet** character.

We are using *MariaDB 5.5*. The option to upgrade to version 10+ is beyond the scope of this question, as we are bound by the client's specifications.

Tried this but I get syntax errors.

```
LOCATE(REGEXP "[\\x00-\\xFF]|^$", myField))
```

> Category  Timestamp   Duration    Message Line    Position Error  24/07/2019
>   4:08:38 PM    0:00:04.612 MySQL Database Error: You have an error in your
>   SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server
>   version for the right syntax to use near 'REGEXP "[\x00-\xFF]|^$",
>   ced.Deckhand)) as FirstWord FROM Crew_Emergency_Dril' at line 1   15  81

I am an SQL Server guy - not familiar with MySQL syntax.

Comment: Don't think you can use regex with `LOCATE()`

Comment: I know. That's the problem. Nothing on web has anything about finding the position or index in a string of a regex pattern. They have plenty of examples of comparing in WHERE clauses etc.

Comment: Found out that I am using 5.5.60-MariaDB which does not have the REGEXP_INSTR() or REGEXP_LIKE() functions! Damn!!!

Comment: Unclear.  Does `_` represent _any_ non-alphanum?  Or a _particular_ non-alphanum?  And are `Kim` and `M` given?  Also "non-ascii" in not the same as "not a letter or a number".

Comment: @RickJames - cool name! EDITed

Comment: Sorry, I don't think there is any way to find that offset using 5.5.

Comment: Thanks @RickJames - no there isn't sadly.